# Siri “take me to work” has stopped working

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

I use hey siri to “take me to work” - which I believe uses my workplace listed on my contact card and then opens maps and directs.

It has now stopped working. As soon as I prompt Siri I immediately get back “hmm...I can’t seem to access that data right now.”

I have tried many further times. On WiFi and cellular. It seems to have stopped working. Siri is working as expected with other commands.

I am on iOS 13.7, I have not changed any data regarding my workplace and I don’t think this was connected to any software update.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you ensure you have an data connection when making the request? If yes, can you verify if Siri is able to process other requests?

Comment: Yes. As said tested on both WiFi and cellular network and not working. Other Siri is working as expected. In fact “Siri take me home” is working as expected!

Comment: It is the emotion detector chip kicking as it senses you don’t really want to go... Similar to the stress chip in photocopiers that trigger a paper jam when you are most rushed...

Comment: Sadly I don’t think Siri is that smart! 